# Is it possible to enque commits to send in batch insted of one by one in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In the picture you can see that I'm doing a lot of commits. I want to wait some time and send all of them together (all values are important).

Is it possible?

I call the action like this:

```
this.updateIsOnStudentList({ materialId: this.material.Id, isOnStudentList: this.material.IsOnStudentList });
```

My action:

```
async function evaluationMaterial({ commit }, { materialId, evaluationState }) {
    commit('UPDATE_EVALUATION_MATERIAL', { materialId, evaluationState });
}
```

My mutation:

```
const UPDATE_EVALUATION_MATERIAL = (state, { materialId, evaluationState }) => {
    let interactionState = state.materialInteractionState[materialId];

    if (!interactionState) {
        interactionState = { ...DEFAULT_INTERACTION_STATE };
    }

    interactionState.evaluationState = evaluationState;

    vueInstance.get().$set(state.materialInteractionState, materialId, interactionState);
};
```

[image]

Comment: How should they be grouped up? by time or by quantity?

Comment: @EderChrono It's a map, so it's a key value object and the last value for that key it's the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my coworkers (https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/10724336) was able to implement the solution of debounce queue... Here's the solution:

My action:

```
function evaluationMaterial({ commit }, { materialId, evaluationState }) {
    _updateInteractionStateDebounced({ commit, materialId, evaluationState });
}
```

The _updateInteractionStateDebounced fuction:

```
const _updateInteractionStateDebounced = debounceQueueUtil.debouncedQueue(_updateInteractionState);
```

The debounceQueueUtil function:

```
const debouncedQueue = function(functionToBeCalled, timeout = 300) {
    const self = {};

    self.daleyedArgs = [];
    self.timeout = timeout;
    self.functionToBeCalled = functionToBeCalled;

    return _saveArgs.bind(self);
};

const _saveArgs = function(args) {
    if (this.debounced) {
        clearTimeout(this.debounced);
    }

    this.daleyedArgs.push(args);
    this.debounced = setTimeout(_callDebouncedFunction.bind(this), this.timeout);
};

const _callDebouncedFunction = function() {
    const args = this.daleyedArgs;
    this.daleyedArgs = [];

    this.functionToBeCalled(args);
};

export default {
    debouncedQueue
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an asynchronous `action` instead of `commit`.
2. Gather promises from your operations and await on `Promise.all()`
3. Then update your `store` as a batch of commits.

Comment: I did'nt understand what you said. I edited my question to you be able to see my action and mutation. And thanks for the answer

Comment: If you want to 'buffer' the commits, or even 'batch' them for that matter, you will need to put them in an action.  There is plenty of info concerning this on the vuex site.  It is not clear if you want to commit many mutations at once, or all together.  It is also not clear if your commits need to be asynchronous or not.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of `vuex` is to make "trackable" all of those commits.
If you want to have a cleaner commit history you would need to create a special commit to wrap all of those changes into one or make your component not to trigger so many `actions/commits` by buffering them. If those changes come from different actions and need to be applied right away, then you're out of luck.

Comment: I want to buffer them but I couldn't think how I can do that because each commit is to update a Map so each value it's important. When I put a debounce I send just the last one. Do you know how I can do that without losing data? thanks for the answer

Comment: Probably you can create an array inside the component data that stores each change, then when the debounce is ready to send the data you send the whole array instead of just the last one.
If the problem is clutter in the vue dev tools, you can use an action and commit for all of those changes and then the debounce sends the last one with a different action and commit, after that you can "filter" the last mutation in the dev tools.

Comment: The component that calls the action only knows it value, so I can't create that array in the component :/ I could create the array inside the action but I don't when to clear the array after the debounce was called :/

Comment: I think we need to know more the context of your component because you only posted the code of the action.